# PHP - HTML: input text to other php to create a string

Tags: php, html, input, text

I have in PHP file this:

```
<input type="text" id="textoBusqueda" name="textoBusqueda">
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="buscar('')">Buscar</button>
```

And in other php in the same html page have this code:

```
$textoBusqueda = $_POST['textoBusqueda'];
    if ($textoBusqueda == '') {
```

But when I open the page and write and text and press Search this text goes out:

```
Notice: Undefined index: textoBusqueda.
```

Comment: This is not a forum. Just see [ask].

Comment: php is ran once when you open the page. If you want stuff to change when you press a button you'll have to use js, not php.

Comment: I assume you are running some javascript (AJAX) to submit the data to PHP. So show us that code

Comment: Show us the full code...

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you have is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="buscar('')">Buscar</button>
<!-----------^^^^^^^^
```

It should be `type="submit"` to submit the form. Also, make sure you have `POST` in the `<form>`'s `method`:

```
<form method="POST" action="/path/to/another.php">
```

If you don't want your page to be changed when you are pressing the button, you have to make sure you aren't submitting the form. You should be using AJAX and JavaScript to change your content of the current page using the `onclick` event.

Comment: if I do it with from, it takes me to another web and it's all in the same but in different PHP files